# Python: deeply copy ast node tree

Tags: python, copy, abstract-syntax-tree, deep-copy

I'm trying to use `deepcopy` (from the `copy` module) to deeply copy a node tree from the `ast` module.

This doesn't seem to work. I'm getting strange errors like `TypeError: required field "name" missing from FunctionDef` when I use the copied result (and I checked it; it really is missing in the copied node), so it didn't correctly copied them.

Is there a trick I can make this working? Or maybe am I missing something?

Comment: With the question like this, it is a guessing game. There are generally no "tricks" please post your relevant code.

Comment: I think this is a good question, and perfectly clear what his problem is, +1.

Comment: @agf: I removed my down-vote just in case. It seems I was wrong about it due to my lack of technical knowledge on the subject, maybe it just looks like a vague question, if that is the case, my apologies to Albert.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, I was wrong. `copy.deepcopy` seems to work correct. The reason I thought it wouldn't work is because of this very odd behavior:

```
import ast, copy
n = ast.FunctionDef(
        name=None,
        args=ast.arguments(args=[], vararg=None, kwarg=None, defaults=[]),
        body=[], decorator_list=[])
n.name = "foo"
ast.fix_missing_locations(n)
n = copy.deepcopy(n)
print n.name
```

This returns `None` in PyPy. Probably a bug because in CPython 2.6, I get `foo`. Strangely, in PyPy, if I remove `name=None` from the `ast.FunctionDef` call, I also get `foo` as the output.

I created a [bug report for PyPy](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues/804) about this.